# What else except media and apps is using space on the Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch, disk-space, watchos

Something unknown is using most of the space on my Apple Watch:
[image]
The listed apps/media account for at most 1GB, yet more than 3.5 are “in use”. What could it be and how can I reclaim some space?

Comment: Mine is suffering the same illness. I am unable to update watchOS because of unsufficient space, still my apps and contents only add up to 565 MB! Usage reports only 664MB available. Where has all the space gone?